# How does git know which file to checkout when using checkout -- somefile?

Tags: git

I've been practicing `git checkout -- somefile.txt` to checkout git files, in case I mess up. How does Git know which file gets checked out from which commit?

i.e.: I write `git checkout -- index.html`. How does Git know which commit to take index.html from, especially as your commit list gets larger and larger?

Comment: To clarify, do you mean `git checkout -- index.html`, with the space, or `git checkout --index.html`, without the space?

Comment: Changed it to spaced

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `git checkout` with a path but without specifying a commit will check out the file from the *index*, i.e. the staging area. So for example if you have staged some changes to a file, and then modified it further and only want to undo those additional changes, then you can use `git checkout -- some/path` to undo those changes.

If your index is clean, i.e. nothing is reported as being staged when using `git status`, then the index will be equivalent to `HEAD`, the currently checked out branch (or commit). So this is a way to undo changes too.

Of course specifying a commit with `git checkout` will always use the file version from that exact revision, regardless of your index.

Comment: Actually that's wrong (I thought the same thing at first): `git checkout -- some/path` checks out the version *from the index*, not from the `HEAD` commit.  In a lot of cases these are the same underlying blob anyway so that it makes no difference, though.

Comment: @torek You are absolutely right, I usually only think about situations with a clean index when writing answers despite me using checkout daily for exactly the purpose of undoing unstaged changes.. Thanks!